# What's the meaning of "that's you done" and what does "'s" stand for?

Tags: meaning, spelling

What does 's stand for in the bold sentence, and what's the meaning of "that's you done"? Could you also provide me with a reference?

> ***Harry entered Madam Malkin's shop alone***, feeling nervous. Madam Malkin was a squat, smiling witch dressed all in mauve.
>   "Hogwarts, dear?" she said, when Harry started to speak. "Got the lot here -- another young man being fitted up just now, in fact. " ***In the back of the shop, a boy with a pale, pointed face was standing on
>   a footstool while a second witch pinned up his long black robes.*** ***Madam Malkin stood Harry on a stool next to him, slipped a long robe over his head, and began to pin it to the right length.***
>   ***"Hello," said the boy, "Hogwarts, too?"
>   "Yes," said Harry.***
>   "My father's next door buying my books and mother's up the street
>   looking at wands," said the boy. He had a bored, drawling voice. "Then
>   I'm going to drag them off to took at racing brooms. I don't see why
>   first years can't have their own. I think I'll bully father into getting
>   me one and I'll smuggle it in somehow."
>   Harry was strongly reminded of Dudley.
>   "Have you got your own broom?" the boy went on.
>   "No," said Harry.
>   "Play Quidditch at all?"
>   "No," Harry said again, wondering what on earth Quidditch could be.
>   "I do -- Father says it's a crime if I'm not picked to play for my
>   house, and I must say, I agree. Know what house you'll be in yet?"
>   "No," said Harry, feeling more stupid by the minute.
>   "Well, no one really knows until they get there, do they, but I know
>   I'll be in Slytherin, all our family have been -- imagine being in
>   Hufflepuff, I think I'd leave, wouldn't you?" "Mmm," said Harry, wishing
>   he could say something a bit more interesting.
>   "I say, look at that man!" said the boy suddenly, nodding toward the
>   front window. Hagrid was standing there, grinning at Harry and pointing
>   at two large ice creams to show he couldn't come in.
>   "That's Hagrid," said Harry, pleased to know something the boy didn't.
>   "He works at Hogwarts."
>   "Oh," said the boy, "I've heard of him. He's a sort of servant, isn't
>   he?"
>   "He's the gamekeeper," said Harry. He was liking the boy less and less
>   every second.
>   "Yes, exactly. I heard he's a sort of savage -- lives in a hut on the
>   school grounds and every now and then he gets drunk, tries to do magic,
>   and ends up setting fire to his bed."
>   "I think he's brilliant," said Harry coldly.
>   "Do you?" said the boy, with a slight sneer. "Why is he with you? Where
>   are your parents?"
>   "They're dead," said Harry shortly. He didn't feel much like going into
>   the matter with this boy.
>   "Oh, sorry," said the other, not sounding sorry at all. "But they were
>   our kind, weren't they?"
>   "They were a witch and wizard, if that's what you mean."
>   "I really don't think they should let the other sort in, do you? They're
>   just not the same, they've never been brought up to know our ways. Some
>   of them have never even heard of Hogwarts until they get the letter,
>   imagine. I think they should keep it in the old wizarding families. ***What's your surname, anyway?
>   But before Harry could answer, Madam Malkin said,*** "**That's you done**, my dear," and Harry, not sorry for an excuse to stop talking to the boy,
>   hopped down from the footstool. "Well, I'll see you at Hogwarts, I suppose," said the drawling boy.

Comment: TL;DR I have to wonder if all that included story line was really necessary for the context of question. CTRL F for 'search browser page' (That's you done) to find the phrase...

Answer (score 17):

It is short for **"That is you done"**. It signifies that Madam Malkin has finished putting pins into robe that Harry is wearing. It is a common (UK) English phrasing used to mean that someone has finished the work, or a stage of the work, that they are doing on behalf of another person. Here the pins have been placed to show the wanted length and next someone can sew the robe to that length.

Comment: in AmE, one might hear "We're done" in this context.

Comment: Another common alternative in some parts of the US is *OK, you're all set.*

Answer (score 16):

*That's you done* is Madame Malkin's way of saying that she has finished Harry's fitting.

This is a very compressed construction:

- *That* simultaneously designates both the last action she performed on Harry and his robes and the entire sequence of actions his fitting required, of which the last action is the climax.
- *you* designates Harry, understood not so much as a person or customer but as one of multiple task, fittings, to be performed. (Note that Draco is also being fitted, and that this is a very busy season for the shop.)
- *you done* is a 'small clause' (a clause without a verb) equivalent to *you BE done*.

So Madame Malkin is announcing that all the actions required by this task are *done*, and she is free to carry on with her next task. And Harry understands that his passive task, too, is *done*, and he is free to stand down.

You might in the same way write your final sentence and say "That's my essay done."

Comment: So you mean "that's you done" is equivalent to "that's you be done"? Could you please anlayze the grammar for me? And what does "'s" stand for? "Is"?

Comment: @user3257464 *'s* = is. All-caps *BE* means 'whatever form of the verb *BE* is appropriate'; I express it this way because *you* here is both the second-person *you* = 'Harry' and the third-person *you* = 'the task of fitting Harry'--but since the verb is omitted we don't have to decide whether *are* or *is* would be more appropriate.

Comment: OK. What are the functions of the other words? subject = that; 's = verb; What are the grammatical functions of you and done?

Comment: @user3257464 The small clause *you done* is the predicative complement of the main clause verb. The subject of the small clause is the pronoun *you* and its predicative complement is the deverbal adjective *done*.

Comment: Isn't this more likely to be used when there are a number of people all waiting? It seems like this construct is more likely to be heard when someone else is up next.

Comment: @J.R. Quite so; or at least that Harry's fitting is just one of many taks Madame Malkin has to perform. I will add that point.

Comment: @user3257464 Native speakers would never expand this to "That is you are done" or anything of the sort.  The more 'formal' way to say this would be "I'm done fitting your robes now, Harry."  ("I am", uncontracted is almost never used in spoken English.)

Comment: @zwol Exactly. Although it follows the rules of English syntax, and is analysable as a regular clause,  it's a *construction*, in the Construction Grammar sense, not an ordinarily predication.

Comment: @StoneyB Oh wow, someone other than me has heard of Construction Grammar! I used to hang out with a bunch of linguists who were all really excited about it.

Comment: @zwol I've only recently started reading up on it, and I'm coming to think it's got the handle on a central linguistic component. But I really dislike CG's graphics. CG doesn't hold a candle to TFG for visual intelligibility, which is crucial for pedagogy. They need a designer.

Comment: @J.R. Possibly. But consider. Standing on a stool in the middle of a shop might embarrass an 11 year old boy. Or perhaps Madam Malkin is old and finds bending over to place the pins is uncomfortable on her back and knees. In both cases they are keen to finish. The phrase "that's you done" signals a release to Harry or it might be an expression of relief from her discomfort.

Comment: @AdrianHHH Or both. It is addressed to Harry: *That's you done, my dear.*

Comment: @user3257464 Incidentally, I'm tempted to think of "That's" pragmatically as an interjection, like French *voilà*. It calls attention to something, announces it, rather than literally equates as the expanded "That is" would suggest. If "behold" weren't nearly impossible to imagine coming out of the character's mouth, it would have about the same function.

Comment: @LukeSawczak Fersher. *There!* is probably a closer equivalent; *Lookythere!* in my native dialect is almost exact.

Comment: @StoneyB Ooh, nice. I like "There!" in terms of tone. I chose "Behold" because it also slots in syntactically without much difficulty: "Behold Christ born" (or some other context in which that word is likely to appear!).